# Adding starred section and subsection to table of content without numbering

Tags: table-of-contents

Hi I am new to latex but I want to remove the numbering for section and subsection and subsubsection and so on but add it to the table of contents as normal.

```
\section*{abc}

\subsection*{adsas}

\subsubsection*{adsda}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is an often asked question: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{abc}` etc. after `\section*{abc}`, equally for `\subsection*` and `\subsubsection*`

Answer (score 5):

If none of your sectioning headers are supposed to be numbered, yet if all of them are supposed to appear in the table of contents, you could proceed by (a) setting the counter `secnumdepth` to `0`, (b) setting the counter `tocdepth` to a suitable positive integer, say, `4`, and (c) using the "unstarred" sectioning commands, viz. `\section`, `\subsection`, etc.

This approach works with `hyperref`, i.e., the entries in the table of contents will be hyperlinks to the corresponding sectioning headers in the body of the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{abc}
\subsection{def}
\subsubsection{ghi}
\paragraph{jkl}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `article` class and no extra packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section*{First}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{First}
\subsection*{First subsec}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{First sub}
\subsection*{First subsubsec}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{First subsub}

\end{document}
```

If this has to be done more than a few times, a more sophisticated approach (using a special class, etc.) is needed.

Comment: Why do you say "with `hyperref` not used" ? code like this works with `hyperref` (at least on not too old versions, possibly even old versions, not tested that).

Comment: @jfbu: I thought because of the missing `\phantomsection`. But apparently, it's not needed any longer for starred sectioning commands

Comment: indeed, it is not needed anymore.

Comment: @jfbu: Thanks, I changed the 'explanation' in the answer!

Comment: +1, but I see you are staying on the cautious legal side, not citing `hyperref` at all ... ;-)

Comment: @jfbu: It's not cautious, I am just lazy :D And the O.P. was not really talkative about his packages/class etc, so I boiled down to the minimal case. I omitted that other famous package `etoc` too ;-)

Comment: precisely from `etoc` I am aware of all the frenetic patches `hyperref` does  to many things, including `\addcontentsline` ...

Comment: whow... I would not recommend engaging into such a tremendous task ! I think hyperref does a good job. I vaguely remember being aware of only one specific problem which was discussed in a question here, but I should make the proper bug report. There is also package `bookmark` which generally should be loaded together with `hyperref`. (+1 for the joke ;-) )

Comment: `hupferref` was too tempting to resist, I perfectly understand that `;-)`...

Comment: the main difficulty with something like `hyperref` is not so much perhaps PDF internals, (of which I surely know even less than you) but that it has to fit into the LaTeX mold with all its contingencies.

Comment: agreed about clean up, but nobody reads us anyhow. We are alone here ...

Comment: don't say their names out loud ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`\addsec` and `\addchap` get no number but are listed in the TOC

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}% or scrbook   
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \addchap{foo}
    \addsec{First}
    \chapter{BAR}
    \section{bar}
\end{document}
```